# Troubleshooting ZPL editing and saving to printer flash

Tags: printing, directory, zebra-printers, zpl

I am using ZebraDesigner to create labels and save them as `.zpl`, files, then manually editing the zpl code to customize it further, and then save it in the printer's directory in onboard flash memory.

I see the .zpl files, listed with their sizes, in the flash directory, but the files are blank when opened, or sometimes contain text belonging to another file.  If I try to paste new code into the file in flash, I'm unable to save it; meaning, I click save, and the web pages merely changes the file extension from ".zpl" to "---", then if I save again, then I get an error the script could not be saved.

I've been unable to get sufficient information nor resolution by contacting Zebra or looking at the product documentation.  Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What method are you using to move the files to the flash memory on the printer?

Comment: Hi Elton, sorry I just saw this response.  I access the printer thru a web browser page and then navigate to the flash memory via the directory.  I can then open and maintain and save, or create new.  Thanks!

Comment: Which printer model are you using? Have you tried using Zebra setup Utilities to upload files?